# Testing thread concurrency with Spock

Tags: multithreading, groovy, testng, spock

Is there a spock equivalent of TestNG's @Test(threadPoolSize=n) that will allow me test the execution of a test, with multiple threads concurrently?

Basically, given a specification like so...

```
class SampleSpec extends Specification {
    def "test concurrent access"(){
        setup:
        //do complex logic
        expect:
        //assert complex logic
    }

}
```

What I want is a way to do this in spock, but with multiple threads spawned concurrently to execute the test method. In TestNG, I could easily achieve this by doing

```
@Test(threadPoolSize=10)
public void testMethod(){
    //do complex logic and assertion

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe there is, but this will probably get a quicker answer in [their discussion forum](http://groups.google.com/group/spockframework?pli=1)

Comment: thanks tim. I have posted to the spock forum as you have suggested

Answer (score 1):

Spock doesn't support this out of the box. It wouldn't be so hard to write a Spock extension for it though. For inspiration, have a look at class `org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TimeoutExtension`.

Comment: How did that go, @GroovyBee?

Comment: If it wouldn't be so hard, can anyone or maybe Spock author provide a working example?